# What if lpCompletionRoutine of WSASend is specified in IOCP model?

Tags: c, asynchronous, tcp, winsock, iocp

The MSDN page for `WriteFileEx` says that it can not be used in IOCP model because it has an argument to specify the completion routine. If the file handle has been associated with an  I/O completion port, then `WriteFileEx` will fail.

However, `WSASend` allows the caller to specify a completion routine as its last argument, while this function can be used in IOCP model.

I examined several examples of WinSock with IOCP, and found the last argument `lpCompletionRoutine` is always null. Is this mandatory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing the documentation says is:

> The completion routine follows the same rules as stipulated for Windows file I/O completion routines.

That might suggest that you cannot mix IOCP and `lpCompletionRoutine` together, like with `WriteFileEx()`.  On the other hand, why would you **want** to mix them together in the first place?  Either the completion port gets the result, or the completion routine does.  Why would you need to use both?

Comment: I just wonder why does MSDN not explicitly document this issue as WriteFileEx.